# Enabling the GPS-receiver on a Dell Latitude

Tags: 18.04, gps

I recently got a new Dell Latitude with a Wireless Broadband connection. According to the boot options, this might include a GPS-device - however I haven't found a way to activate it yet.

What tools should I use to see the GPS location?

`journalctl -b | grep -i "GPS"` gives me `Sep 30 00:14:53 pietervdvn-Latitude-5591 systemd[1]: Listening on GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets.` `lshw` nor `lsusb` give any indication about GPS.

It is about a brand-new Dell Latitude 5591. The BIOS-Options indicated that a GPS-receiver might have come with it - although it could not (yet?) be implemented in their drivers.

Comment: Use `sudo lshw` to see your hardware. Use `journalctl -b` to page through your system startup logs and look for "`GPS`". Use `lsusb` to see USB-connected devices, Without more info, including your model number, we can't help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing these out! I've updated the question with the output of those commands.

Comment: Is the gps daemon running and on what is it listening?  post the output of  ps auxww |grep [g]psd

Comment: root      1049  0.0  0.0 107684  8040 ?        Ss   00:14   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
pieterv+  9822  0.0  0.0  21536  1004 pts/2    S+   01:15   0:00 grep --color=auto psd